# Multiple installations of Eclipse on Mac OSX

Tags: eclipse

I use Eclipse for everything. Python, Django, GWT, Android... But when you install all the plugins, Eclipse becomes very slow.

Is there a way that I can set it up so that there are two or more icons for Eclipse in the Applications directory, each for specific task?

Thanks

Comment: On Windows just putting different copies of Eclipse in different directories does the trick. Not sure if the equivalent can be done on Mac

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Developing in Eclipse for the past few years, I've found it's just easier to have several copies of the Eclipse directory, one for each kind of development I do (Android, java app, Grails).   It's sometimes cumbersome installing new versions of Eclipse or new versions of the common plugins (Subclipse, etc), but it does make Eclipse start-up MUCH faster.

Simply create another install directory for Eclipse, with another shortcut to it, and only install the plugins you need for that dev environment.  I use a different workspace for each one, though I'm not sure that's necessary, as long as you're using the same version of Eclipse for each install.