# How do I manage multiple packages in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, package, explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to view hierarchical package structure in Eclipse package explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915961/how-to-view-hierarchical-package-structure-in-eclipse-package-explorer)

If I have many packages, how can I organize them in Eclipse?  I want them all in the same workspace, and I want to be able to quickly go back and forth.  So, if I have packages A,B,C,D,E, and I want them in a folder like "A thru E", and then I have packages "F,G,H,I,J", and I want them in a folder like "F thru J"... how can I do this?  I don't want to have them in separate workspaces, and I don't want all of these packages listed invidiually in the package explorer.  I'd like to keep my package explorer neat, and I only want three or four packages showing at any time.

Comment: What's wrong with displaying all the packages side by side? How would you know there are others if they would be hidden? One hint though: did you try enabling the hierarchical package display?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915961/how-to-view-hierarchical-package-structure-in-eclipse-package-explorer

Answer (score 2):

Do packages A-E have anything in common? If so, just create a separate project for them - and likewise a project for F-J. I wouldn't start doing this *arbitrarily* though - does it really matter if you see 10 packages? I use far more than that day-to-day, and it doesn't bother me.

However, I *do* find it makes a difference to use the hierarchical package presentation instead of flat - that makes it *much* easier to manage a large number of packages which involve a deep "hierarchy". Even though the package hierarchy is flat as far as the language/JVM is concerned, it's meaningful to *me* as a developer.

Comment: I meant to say "Projects" instead of "Packages".  This is actually not a duplicate question, I just goofed the terminology because the tab says "Package Explorer".  I'm going to open a new question substituting these terms if it's alright with everyone.  Maybe I will give better examples too.

Comment: Ugh. "Working Set" is what I was looking for. "Working Set" lets me create a "heirarchial view" of Projects. Sorry for botching the question. I found the answer here for what it's worth: [How do you organize 100+ projects in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310928/how-do-you-organize-100-projects-in-eclipse)